# Ubuntu One app doesn't autostart after I renamed Ubuntu One folder

Tags: ubuntu-one, startup, autostart

I renamed the default Ubuntu One folder (**Ubuntu One** to **.Ubuntu One**) and after that the *Ubuntu One client* doesn't start when computer starts.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution for all users from the same machine

If you want to make **.Ubuntu One** folder (and, like this, make it hidden) the default folder for Ubuntu One application for all users from the same machine, you have to edit three files where this directory is set.

1. Edit **`/etc/xdg/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf`** file with root privileges, find and change the line:

   ```
   root_dir.default = ~/Ubuntu One
   ```

   with the line:

   ```
   root_dir.default = ~/.Ubuntu One
   ```
2. Edit **`/usr/bin/ubuntuone-launch`** file with root privileges, find and change the line:

   ```
   U1ROOT = os.path.expanduser('~/Ubuntu One/')
   ```

   with the line:

   ```
   U1ROOT = os.path.expanduser('~/.Ubuntu One/')
   ```
3. Edit **`/etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop`** file with root privileges, find and change the line:

   ```
   Exec=/bin/sh -c '[ -d "$HOME/Ubuntu One" ] && ubuntuone-launch'
   ```

   with the line:

   ```
   Exec=/bin/sh -c '[ -d "$HOME/.Ubuntu One" ] && ubuntuone-launch'
   ```
4. Another one thing that you must to do is to edit the command for Ubuntu One application in **Startup Applications**:

   [image: Startup Application Preferences]
5. Run the following command in terminal:

   ```
   rename 's/Ubuntu\ One$/.Ubuntu\ One/' /home/*/Ubuntu\ One
   ```

   to rename **Ubuntu One** to **.Ubuntu One** for all other users.
6. Finally restart Ubuntu One application from terminal with the following command:

   ```
   u1sdtool --quit && u1sdtool --start
   ```

### Solution only for the current user

As [dobey](https://askubuntu.com/users/50737/dobey) suggest in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336192/ubuntu-one-app-doesnt-autostart-after-i-renamed-ubuntu-one-folder/336207#comment428517_336207), the above solution may be overwritten when installing updates, so it will be better to change the settings for each individual user:

1. Copy `syncdaemon.conf` file from `/etc/xdg/ubuntuone/` to `~/.config/ubuntuone/`.
2. Edit the copied file (`~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf`), find and change the line:

   ```
   root_dir.default = ~/Ubuntu One
   ```

   with the line:

   ```
   root_dir.default = ~/.Ubuntu One
   ```
3. Edit and change the command for Ubuntu One application in **Startup Applications** to:

   ```
   /bin/sh -c '[ -d "$HOME/.Ubuntu One" ] && u1sdtool --start'
   ```

   [image: Startup Application Preferences]
4. Finally restart Ubuntu One application from terminal with the following command:

   ```
   u1sdtool --quit && u1sdtool --start
   ```

Comment: Yeah, but I actually want to get rid of this folder or at least make it invisible. Besides, when I press 'Open the Ubuntu One Folder' **.Ubuntu One** opens without problems.

Comment: @Hofmn This is contradictory with what you said in the question: "*Ubuntu One client don't start*"

Comment: DO NOT edit `/etc/xdg/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf` with your settings. You should create a `~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf` file instead, and only include the sections and settings you intend to change, in it. Changing the one inside `/etc` will break configuration for other users, and may be overwritten when installing updates. Likewise, you should copy the autostart .desktop file to `~/.config/autostart/` before editing it.

Comment: @dobey Why do you are so scared by editing those files? If you pay attention, I said that changing those files will affect all users. Anyway, if you create `~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf` file you will not solve absolutely nothing!. The file `~/.config/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop` already exists and if you do not change the value fur **Ubuntu One** folder in `/usr/bin/ubuntuone-launch` file, the Ubuntu One will not autostart! I presented this solution for all users and I mentioned this. And if you know a good solution only for the current user, you are free to post it!

Comment: @dobey I jut edited my answer, so you can retreat your vote.